# How to remove an empty div created by Google Maps InfoWindow (Close info window on map click also close older info window's when opening new one)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason, Google is rendering an empty div in Google Maps infoWindow card. I'm following the normal practice in which I'm initiating Google Maps via initMap() and to add infoWindow I'm using:

```
if (props.content) {

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: props.content
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

How do I remove this div? or place my content in the div?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove such a `div`?

Comment: What is `props.content`?  Passing an HTMLElement as the InfoWindow content seems to work: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k6703q5y/2/).

Comment: @SMAKSS I want to enter content inside that div or remove it. Because that div has right-click disabled and on my div you can right-click. So it doesn't give good experience. I want to disable right click hence I want to enter content in this div or completely remove it.

Comment: @geocodezip the purpose of props.content is to check the content.

Comment: @geocodezip Can you help with disabling right-click on the content too, please?

Comment: I was asking about `props.content` so I could set up a [mcve] that demonstrated your issue.  But it would be better if you did that.  The right click issue is another question (please don't extend your questions in the comments, comments are for clarification of the existing question, not to ask additional questions, no matter how related you may feel they are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting a `div` in javascript you can simply use `remove()` function via dot notation.

Just like this:

```js
document.getElementById("element").remove();
```

But since you don't have a special id or class in your desired DOM item that couldn't be a solution. So you have to **get the parent node and remove its children**. All you have to do is to use `removeChild(/*element.lastChild*/)`. So it will be something like this:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.gm-style-iw-d');
element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
```

---

### UPDATE

If you want to disable the context menu in your other `div` to make them look like the same, there are two ways to do that.

First, you can do this by manipulating HTML itself like this:

```html
<div oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
```

Or by manipulating the DOM after the initial load:

HTML

```html
<div id='elementId'></div>
```

Javascript

```js
document.getElementById('elementId').addEventListener('contextmenu', function() {
  return false;
});
```

### UPDATE 2

This is not the best approach to achieve what you wanted but you can do this in order to **close the dialog whenever the user clicks anywhere in the map except marker and dialog itself**. According to the [google map document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) you can use `.close()` method to close `InfoWindow` just like this:

```js
function addMarker(props) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: props.coords,
    map: map,
  });

  // Check for custom icon
  if (props.iconImage) {
    // Set icon image
    marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
  }

  // Check content
  if (props.content) {

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: props.content
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      setTimeout(() => {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gm-ui-hover-effect')[0].remove();
      }, 1);
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    infoWindow.close();
  });
}
```

### UPDATE 3

To achieve closing old `infoWindow` you should create a unique `infoWindow` and update its content to having just one that gets closed/opened on each `marker.click`. So in this way, it will be working like a charm.

```js
var infoWindow = null;

// Add marker function
function addMarker(props) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: props.coords,
    map: map,
    // icon: './img/marker1.png'
  });

  // Check for custom icon
  if (props.iconImage) {
    // Set icon image
    marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
  }

  // Check content
  if (props.content) {

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (infoWindow) {
        infoWindow.close();
      }
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      setTimeout(() => {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gm-ui-hover-effect')[0].remove();
      }, 10);

    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    infoWindow.close();
  });
}
```

Here is the link to the working demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SMAKSS/cm2Lng6j/6/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212943/discussion-on-answer-by-smakss-how-to-remove-an-empty-div-created-by-google-maps).